# What is add() method being used for in snap.svg script?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I was just getting my feet wet with snap.svg and so I have the below code to load my svg:

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    // what is the below line of code doing ??
        var g = Snap();
        g.attr({
            viewBox: [0, 0, 800, 600]
        });
        Snap.load("samsonite.svg", function (f) {
            // function getShift(dot) {
            //     return "t" + (400 - dot.x) + "," + (300 - dot.y);
            // }
            console.log(f);
            var gr = f.select('#outer-most-group'),
            top = g.g();
            top.add(gr);
    });
};
</script>
```

Now if I break down the code right:

```
var g = Snap(); // create an instance of snap.
```

And

```
Snap.load("samsonite.svg", function (f) { // Load the SVG using Snap.load()
```

But I am not confidently understanding the next two lines of code:

```
top = g.g();
top.add(gr); // I don't know what top is at this point but the add()
             // method is being used to add gr, which is basically
             // the outermost <g> element in the SVG I have.
```

Would somebody please explain what the above two lines are doing ? Especially the line `top = g.g()`.

Comment: http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.add - the docs say it's the same as [`append`](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.append), which appends the given element to the current one.

Answer (score 1):

the Snap method `g()` creates a "group" element (`<g>`), in the same way that `g.circle()` would create a circle element. so `top` refers to the group element you just created. `gr` is also a group element; it refers to the element matching the selector `'#outer-most-group'`. so, `top.add(gr)` is adding a group from the loaded svg file to a group you've just created on your instance of snap.

more on the group element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g